# local variable 'animSet' referenced before assignment Source filmaker

Tags: python

I'm trying to use python scripting in the source film maker to try to import a model, but keep receiving an "unboundlocalerror: local variable 'animSet' referenced before assignment." what am I doing wrong?

```
baseName = "secret_spy" 


modelPath = "models\\player\\hwm\\spy.mdl" 
#The short path to the model. If you use an antislash '\', be sure to double it, as it is a special char.

newAnimSet = sfmUtils.CreateModelAnimationSet( baseName, modelPath )
def CreateModelAnimationSet( baseName, modelPath ):
    ''' Create a model and animation set for that model and add the model to the scene'''
    
    shot = sfm.GetCurrentShot()
    model = sfm.CreateModel( modelPath )
    if ( model != None ):
        animSet = sfm.CreateAnimationSet( baseName, target=model )
        if ( animSet != None ):            
            dag = vs.CreateElement( "DmeDag", baseName, shot.GetFileId() )
            dag.AddChild( model )
            shot.scene.AddChild( dag )
    
    return animSet
```

Answer (score 1):

Your variable needs to be initialized. In the case where your `if` statement doesn't evaluate to true there won't be a variable to return. You will need to handle the case where it isn't set where ever the function is called, though.

```
baseName = "secret_spy" 


modelPath = "models\\player\\hwm\\spy.mdl" 
#The short path to the model. If you use an antislash '\', be sure to double it, as it is a special char.

newAnimSet = sfmUtils.CreateModelAnimationSet( baseName, modelPath )
def CreateModelAnimationSet( baseName, modelPath ):
    ''' Create a model and animation set for that model and add the model to the scene'''
    
    shot = sfm.GetCurrentShot()
    model = sfm.CreateModel( modelPath )
    animSet = None
    if ( model != None ):
        animSet = sfm.CreateAnimationSet( baseName, target=model )
        if ( animSet != None ):            
            dag = vs.CreateElement( "DmeDag", baseName, shot.GetFileId() )
            dag.AddChild( model )
            shot.scene.AddChild( dag )
    
    return animSet
```

Comment: Good to mention that best practices indicate that `is` is used to compare against `None`.
That would mean `if model is not None` and `if animSet is not None`. You can also drop the parenthesis.